# Hide "Requirement already satisfied" warning

Tags: pip

We have a shell script that automatically prepares virtual environment and then runs tests in it. Part of the script installs requirements:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When the script is run multiple times it prints a warning for each requirement:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): discover==0.4.0
...
```

I need to run the installation step every time in case that someone adds a new requirement. I understand why the warning is displayed. The problem is that it clutters the test output.

Is there a way how to disable/hide this warning?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt | grep -v 'Requirement already satisfied'`?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a real solution yet, it appears the pip team doesn't want to add another no-warn flag and the ticket for a more generic solution is open since years: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6119. Maybe do an inquiry there to let them know that this is still a desired feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the errors go to *stderr*, this `bash` code should do it:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt 2> >(grep -v 'Requirement already satisfied' 1>&2)
```

For more recent versions of 'pip', where errors go to *stdout*, the above can be simplified to:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt | grep -v 'already satisfied'
```

Comment: Modern pip seems to write to stdout, so the redirection is not required anymore. Just `pip install -r requirements.txt | grep -v 'already satisfied'` is fine.

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me:

`pip install -r requirements.txt | grep -v 'already satisfied'`

Comment: This worked for me as well, while the accepted answer didn't. It seems that the warning is sent to `stdout` now instead of `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows** users landing here this can be resolved in a virtually similar manner using Find

```
pip install -r requirements.txt | find /V "already satisfied"
```

and as answered in a [Windows specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67953925/10802527) the other way is

```
pip install -r requirements.txt | findstr /V /C:"Requirement already satisfied"
```