# Hide “Requirement already satisfied” warning from pip in Windows cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, pip

This question is similar to: [Hide "Requirement already satisfied" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350951/hide-requirement-already-satisfied-warning) but I want to have solution working in Windows cmd.

---

I have a cmd script that automatically prepares virtual environment. Part of the script installs requirements:

```
python -m venv .venv --prompt "%CurrDirName%"
.\.venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When the script is run multiple times it prints a warning for each requirement:

```sh
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator in c:\moje\programowanie\projekty2021\proj1\.venv\lib\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->jupyter->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\moje\programowanie\projekty2021\proj1\.venv\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\moje\programowanie\projekty2021\proj1\.venv\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (0.5.1)
...
```

I need to run the installation step every time in case that someone adds a new requirement. I understand why the warning is displayed. The problem is that it clutters the console output.

Is there a way how to disable/hide this warning?

I still want to see other messages or errors. I want to disable only those warnings, not others.

Comment: `pip install -q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows only messages without `Requirement already satisfied`:

```
.\.venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt | findstr /V /C:"Requirement already satisfied"
```

This shows no messages:

```
.\.venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt >null
```

Comment: I still want to see other messages or errors. I edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: .\.venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt  | findstr /V /C:"Requirement already satisfied"