# Hide "Requirement already satisfied" warning from pip in Kaggle kernel

Tags: pip, kaggle

I want to install **dataprep** package in Kaggle Kernel.
As simple:

`!pip install dataprep`

is working but display many line *Requirement already satisfied*

```
Requirement already satisfied: dataprep in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dataprep) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: levenshtein<0.13.0,>=0.12.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dataprep) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: varname<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from dataprep) (0.8.1)
......
```

From recommendation in stackoverflow I try with:

```
!pip install -q dataprep
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
beatrix-jupyterlab 3.1.1 requires google-cloud-bigquery-storage, which is not installed.
preprocessing 0.1.13 requires nltk==3.2.4, but you have nltk 3.6.3 which is incompatible.
flask 2.0.2 requires Jinja2>=3.0, but you have jinja2 2.11.3 which is incompatible.
featuretools 1.0.0 requires dask[dataframe]>=2021.2.0, but you have dask 2.30.0 which is incompatible.
distributed 2021.10.0 requires dask==2021.10.0, but you have dask 2.30.0 which is incompatible.
```

How does my kernel not display  *Requirement already satisfied* in the first way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a solution exists at

[Hide "Requirement already satisfied" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350951/hide-requirement-already-satisfied-warning)

`pip install -r requirements.txt | grep -v 'already satisfied'`