# Hide many requirement warnings

Tags: python, pip

This question is following the question [Hide "Requirement already satisfied" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350951/hide-requirement-already-satisfied-warning).

In that solved question, we can hide all "Requirement already satisfied" warning.
But if the `pip install package-name` contained more than one-style warnings, example **Requirement already satisfied** and **Collection**. How can we hide it?

Comment: What kind of warning is *Collection*? Why do you want to hide it? Is there anything specific that you want to achieve, e.g. automatically extract some kind of information from the output?

Comment: Collecting dataprep
  Downloading dataprep-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting python-stdnum<2.0,>=1.16
  Downloading python_stdnum-1.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (943 kB)..... So long and it is not useful to me. @André

Comment: It may help to rephrase the question. What parts of the output **are** you interested in? Do you programmically parse the command output or does the output just personally annoy you?

Comment: Thank you @André, only personal, I want to my code look like short and be easy to read. Example in [this kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/phanttan/disastertweet-prepareddata), `!pip install dataprep` make many warnings/reports. I want it short as possible.